# Rerender child of composite component

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, render, composite-component

Is there a way to specify a child component of a composite component to re-render using f:ajax:

```
<f:ajax render="compositeComponent:childComponent" />
```

From my brief experimentation it doesn't seem possible to reference them but I wondered if there was an alternate strategy to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine. It's fully client side (i.e., the JSF-generated JavaScript code locates it in the HTML DOM tree).

Probably you referenced the wrong client ID. Open the page in the webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source*, locate the generated HTML element in the page source and determine its `id` attribute. The one which you specify in the `render` attribute should refer either absolutely (prefix with `:`) or relatively (as compared to the parent `UINamingContainer` component) to it.

Another possible cause is that you have put the `rendered` attribute on the very same composite component's child which evaluated `false` which in turn caused that the generated HTML element is totally missing in the HTML DOM tree. You would then like to put the `rendered` attribute on a child of that component instead, like so:

```
<h:panelGroup id="childComponent">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" rendered="#{bean.rendered}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: yeah. you're right. when i created a more basic example it worked fine.